# determine if a toric variety is Gorenstein

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, toric-varieties, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ a simply connected group over $k$ and $car(k)=0$.

Let $T_{+}=(T\times T)/Z_{G}$ we consider the closure $\overline{T}_{+}$ of the torus $T_{+}$ in $\prod End(V_{\omega_{i}})\times\prod\limits_{\alpha\in\Delta}A^{1}_{\alpha}$

by the map $(z,t)\mapsto (\omega_{i}(z)\rho_{\omega_{i}}(t),\alpha_{i}(z))$

where $\Delta$ is the set of simple roots, $\omega_{i}$ the fundamental weights and $\rho_{\omega_{i}}, V_{\omega_{i}}$ the irreducible representation of highest weight $\omega_{i}$.

We already know by general theorems that $\overline{T}_{+}$ is normal and Cohen-Macaulay.

Do we have that $\overline{T}_{+}$ is Gorenstein, complete intersection?

Comment: Does-it concern any toric variety ? Or only T¯+ ?

Comment: only $\overline{T}_{+}$

Comment: For Gorensteiness ,did you try the canonical line bundle criterion ? (Is the canonical line bundle of T¯+ well computed ?).